# make map fixed (no scrolling)

Tags: android, dictionary

I tried to make my map fixed on android application this is my XML:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map_profil"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.n3rd.tousfacteurs.postmen.WorkaroundMapFragment"
/>
```

Comment: You need to handle LatLngBounds on your map. I recommend reading more into Google maps.

Comment: Try to override onTouchEvent() and return true